# Make a real-time (dynamical systems) simulations where user can interact

Tags: javascript, html, user-controls, simulation

I'd like to use HTML and Javascript to simulate some system, let's say a discretized differential equation like

```
x_new = x_old + factor * (bound - x_old)
```

Now I would like to give the user looking at the HTML page the possibility to interfere in real time, for example change the value of `factor` with some slider and see its effect on the dynamical system.

Now in principle I know the basics to do that but I am having trouble with the following issue:

I need to set the simulation speed at some value and as the calculation is (obviously) very quick, I need to insert artificial waiting times (such that the simulations feels like "real time" and does not just whizz past in a tenth of a second).  At the same time I would like to let the user interact with all the elements without the window "freezing up" due to some waiting process. All in all, I have the following specs:

- Real time simulation of some process
- User can interact at any time (using buttons and sliders) and see changes in the dynamics

I am sure that something like that already exists so could anyone point out to me a "best practice" example? Alternatively, a tip on how to resolve the issue myself would also be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code here as a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for the "sliding" part, you could use some external components, but that depends a bit on the JavaScript framework you're using and /or if you use Jquery or things like that.

For simulating a lower speed, you could use the window.setTimeout.
This function basically executes another function after waiting an amount of milliseconds.

```
setTimeout(
        function(){
            ///Make something here 
            }, 3000); //execute it after 3000 milliseconds passed.
```

I made a very basic pure javascript/html sample in jsfiddle. This should get you started.

https://jsfiddle.net/pimboden40/L65te3f2/17/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CodeHacker, I was able to implement the thing I wanted. Below is a slightly adapted version of his suggestion, now with a "real-time" sim you can change. I have used recursive calls of the updating function together with a global counter variable in order to create a continous simulation. Code:

```
function calculate(x_old, factor, bound){
        return x_old + factor * (bound - x_old);
}

var cnt = 0;

function callDelayed(){
        console.log(cnt)
        var x_old = Number(document.getElementById('x-old').value) ;
        var factor =Number(document.getElementById('factor').value) ;
        var bound = Number(document.getElementById('bound').value) ;
         setTimeout(
            function(){
                var calculation =  calculate(x_old, factor, bound);
                  document.getElementById('result').value = calculation; 
                  console.log("Finished step " + cnt); 
                  // update x_old
                  document.getElementById('x-old').value = document.getElementById('result').value
                  cnt = cnt+1;
                  // if time has not run out, update again
                  if (cnt <= 100)
                  {
                      callDelayed()
                  }
                  else
                    return
                 }, 100);

}
```

Is that (recursive calling) considered bad practice or is that alright?

Comment: Recursive calling is alright. Glad I could help. Accept as answer please. Thanks